# How to filter out data from a print out message

Tags: python, filter, printing

I have this one problem, where I print out a message response from a website(JSON response), and the response I get is this.

Here is my model with fake data:

`{"token": "MTAxOTAwNjM4NjEyMzg0OTkwMQ.8hkyLV.n0ir2UA4qFE5pXen9YnPtFzgn4xP8tHmVmmkrl", "user_settings": {"locale": "en-US", "theme": "dark"}, "user_id": "101900638614857883"}`

And, if I only want the value of `"token"` data which are this `(MTAxOTAwNjM4NjEyMzg0OTkwMQ.8hkyLV.n0ir2UA4qFE5pXen9YnPtFzgn4xP8tHmVmmkrl)` and I want to store it into a txt file, is there any good way to do it?

Thank you, guys!

I tried `print(r.text('token'))` but it did not work, since it only works on printing the category of the data's `(like : Category : {"token" : 'daefafa', "user-id" : 'er121231231', more})`

Comment: Parse the JSON with `json.loads`, then directly access the `token` key on the `dict`.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask], [mre] and the other links found on those pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python, JSON is treated as a dictionary.
To filter it use dictionary comprehension

```py
tokenData = {key: val for key,val in data_json.items() if key == 'token'}
```

### Full Code Snippet :

```py
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json

url = "enter-your-url"
response = urlopen(url)

data_json = json.loads(response.read())
print(type(data_json))  # <class 'dict'>

#use dict comprehension 
jsonToken = {key: val for key,val in data_json.items() if key == 'result'}

strToken = json.dumps(jsonToken)   
# Only string json can be written to files

with open('data.txt','w') as file:
    file.write(strToken)
file.close()
```

Comment: Its my pleasure, Open Source Python developers do check out : [Python Project](https://github.com/mahimai-raja/open-source-python-projects-2023)

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the JSON into a dictionary using `json.loads()`. Like this:

```
import json

# ...
# request-getting code
# ...

data = json.loads(r.text)
print(data['token'])
```